# Office 365 development API like Google Docs?

Tags: google-data-api, office365

Is there a Office 365 development API like Google Docs? I was searching web but I was unable to find.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There's an [API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd637749%28v=exchg.80%29.aspx) for the Exchange part of Office 365. Lync also has an API. You can also managed Sharepoint sites via the [Client Object Model](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee535231.aspx), web services or WebDAV APIs for uploading and downloading files

However I don't believe there's anything for manipulating documents online outside of using WebDav to push to a sharepoint site.

Comment: Blowdart's answer is right for now unfortunately, but I am hoping to get some answers on their forum here: http://community.office365.com/en-us/f/154/p/7521/30580.aspx

Answer (score 6):

For anyone who's still coming across this page: There is now Office 365 APIs in preview covering the Files, Mail, Calendar and Contacts APIs. Visit http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn605892(v=office.15).aspx for more information

Answer (score 5):

SharePoint 2010 introduced the Client Side Object Model and a REST API for working with list data.  SharePoint 2013 builds on top of that with the app model, enabling a broader support for CSOM and REST using OAuth for app authorization that enables you to build apps (including working with documents, among many other features of SharePoint in O365).  You can find more information at:

http://dev.office.com

There is a new Office 365 API that was announced recently at the SharePoint Conference that broadens this support further to enable client applications to call those services as well.

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn605892(v=office.15).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn605892%28v=office.15%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Simple answer: not yet.  Office **365** does have a developer guide on Sharepoint - http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=17069  .

But it appears their API is not the same as Google Docs because it is still early.

Comment: Being closed source doesn't exclude an API (there is an SDK for Office and has been for years). Nor is Office = Office 365, which the question addresses. And of course Google Docs is proprietary and closed source too.

Comment: The question isn't asking if the Office 365 API is the same as the Google Docs API. It is asking if Office 365 has publicly accessible API documentation, the Google docs has publicly accessible API documentation. He's wondering, because he searched for Office 365 API documentation, but couldn't find any.